# Экспорт данных в html webapp из тг бота, для вывода данных

Tags: javascript, html, aiogram

markup.add(KeyboardButton("Открыть магазин", web_app=WebAppInfo(url="https://.github.io/"))) Открываю web_app через кнопку, нужно, чтобы в html отображались объекты, лежащие в БД, чтобы можно было их передать и вывести на страницу, как это сделать? Обшарил весь интернет, нигде не написано, подскажите пожалуйста

Открывал атрибуты WebAppInfo, однако туда никаких данных передать нельзя

Answer (score 0):

На стороне бота

```py
markup.add(KeyboardButton("Открыть магазин", web_app=WebAppInfo(url="https://test.github.io/?foo=bar")))
```

На стороне веб-страницы

```js
const url = new URL(location.href, location.origin);
console.log(url.searchParams.get('foo')); // bar
```